# CALayer/UIView crashes when I touch the UIVIew

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, calayer, stack-trace

Iam using a custom layer for drawing on my `UIView`. And to invalidate and update the layer I need to set my view to be the delegate of my `CALayer`. When this is done it draws my text correctly **but** when the view receives touches the app crashes.
What I am a doing wrong?

```
- (void) layoutSubView {
    if (drawLayer == nil) {
        drawLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
        [drawLayer setDelegate:self];
        [[self layer] addSublayer:drawLayer];
    }
    [drawLayer setFrame:[self bounds]]; 
    [drawLayer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Above is my code to setup the CALayer, and below is the overridden drawLayer method.

```
- (void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer 
     inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {

        if (layer == drawLayer) {
        UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
        [self drawTitle:ctx];
        UIGraphicsPopContext();
    }
}
```

Here is the stack.

[image]

Comment: have you overridden touchesBegan/Moved/End? what is the crash cause?

Comment: Nope I haven't overridden them, should I just to prevent the crash?

Comment: I don't think so, but I would try and override `convertPoint:fromLayer` to see which arguments are passed in... you did not say which is the exact error message you get with the crash...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a `UIView` object to be the delegate of a layer other than its own layer. Its stated [`here`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW31). You will need to assign some other object as its delegate.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should RTFM =) Ill create a separate class for this layer then or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Nope. I take the same route with layers.